# Does Android ColorMatrix setSaturation() support values greater than one?

Tags: android, image-manipulation, colormatrix

Looking at the Android docs, the [ColorMatrix setSaturation() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html#setSaturation(float)) says:

> Set the matrix to affect the saturation of colors. A value of 0 maps the color to gray-scale. 1 is identity.

I'm trying to boost the saturation (in terms of HSL/HSV) to get more intense colors, so I passed in 1.6 and it seems to work.  I've run into device-specific issues with Android layout shadowRadius values less than 1, so is there a danger of those types of issues with this parameter and exceeding the specified range?

Comment: No, it does **not**. `1 means 100%` in ColorMatrices. It's like that in every other language, including VB.NET and C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range for the saturation is indeed between 0 and 1. But lets take a look at the code for the setSaturation() method. [(Android is open source)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.java#L234):

```
public void setSaturation(float sat) {
    reset();
    float[] m = mArray;

    final float invSat = 1 - sat; //<---------invSat will be negative if sat bigger than 1
    final float R = 0.213f * invSat;
    final float G = 0.715f * invSat;
    final float B = 0.072f * invSat;

    m[0] = R + sat; m[1] = G;       m[2] = B;
    m[5] = R;       m[6] = G + sat; m[7] = B;
    m[10] = R;      m[11] = G;      m[12] = B + sat;
}
```

The part of the code that we care about is pointed out. As you can see,The method will take your input and subtract it from 1. If you input a value greater than 1, this will result in a negative value for the invSat, and as you can see it may cause bigger problems as well.

Comment: As someone who learned iOS before Android, I didn't know they meant THAT open source... Dunno what I thought it meant. Thanks for the link and quick reply!